# Not able to get value from custom table in PowerApps portal

Tags: powerapps-portal, liquid-template

I had created a custom table(entity) in dataverse of power app portal and added some dummy data. Table name is "TestTable" and created a column "TestColumn". I am trying to get data from this in powerapps portal using liquid query.

```
{{entities.cr3c9_testtable['ef5398fe-c68f-eb11-b1ac-000d3af25ac1'].cr3c9_testcolumn}}
```

I am able to get value in portal studio as shown below.

[image]

However, when I browse this site, it's not showing.

[image]

I tried to clear cache multiple times but having same result.

Please let me know if anyone has idea on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check if table/column name is correct. Since the column is named Test Column it should be something like cr3c9_TestColumn.
Also check if you have entity permissions for cr3c9_testtable with read access and assign appropriate web roles to that permission.